# Why the output is different from what I expect?

Tags: c++, c++11

I got a simple program like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class B {
    protected:
        int     data = 0;
    public:
        B() { cout << "B() ctor\n";}
        virtual ~B() { cout << "~B()\n"; }
        virtual void method() { cout << "data in B: " << data << "\n"; }
    };

    class A : public B 
    {
        int dataA = 2;
    public:
        A() { cout << "A() ctor\n"; }
        ~A() { cout << "~A()\n"; }
        void method() { cout << "data in A: " << dataA << "\n"; }
    };

    {
        B* fptrList[]{ &B{}, &A{}};
        for (auto& itr : fptrList)
            itr->method();
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a result I expect:

```
B() ctor
B() ctor
A() ctor
data in B: 0
data in A: 2
~A()
~B()
~B()
```

Here is the actual result when I ran this program:

```
B() ctor
~B()
B() ctor
A() ctor
~A()
~B()
data in B: 0
data in B: 0
```

My questions are:

- Why the output is different from what I expect?
- How can method() be called after ~A() and ~B() get called?
- Why method() of class B get called twice?

Comment: It's just UB, try to explain the behavior is meaningless.

Comment: I don't think so. You see the calls to method() got success and printed out correct data's value. If those objects actually destroyed, the call to method() which accesses to "data" member should raise a runtime error.

Comment: This is UB, nothing is guaranteed. It might raise runtime error, might work well (unfortunately).

Answer (score 5):

This program cannot be explained, because it exhibits undefined behavior.

Translation: it's buggy. It's taking an address of temporary objects, and then attempts to dereference them, after the temporary have been destructed.

A good C++ compiler will even tell you that the program is broken, and will refuse to participate in this disaster:

```
t.C: In function ‘int main()’:
t.C:26:27: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
         B* fptrList[]{ &B{}, &A{}};
                           ^
t.C:26:33: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
         B* fptrList[]{ &B{}, &A{}};
                                 ^
```

Any output from this program is meaningless garbage.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what's going on:

- You initialize `fptrList` to addresses of temporary variables `A` and `B`
- The temporary variables get destroyed right after their addresses are taken, so your code has undefined behavior.
- Proper way of doing what you are trying to do it is to use operator `new` with smart pointers, or to make instances outside initializer.

Here is one possible fix:

```
{
    B b;
    A a;
    B* fptrList[]{ &b, &a };
    for (auto& itr : fptrList)
        itr->method();
}
```

Comment: Quick question: Why are the temporaries destroyed right after their address is taken and not after the statement is finished?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Since temporaries are not needed after their address is taken, the compiler is free to decide on when to call the destructor. It looks like your compiler decided to destroy them right away.

Comment: I know your "fix" is proper way. I just gave a try and saw how strange it was.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is undefined behavior, but the question is still interesting why it is **this** undefined behavior.

- **Why are constructors/destructors are called in this order?** As already established, you creates temporary objects which are created/destroyed one after each other.
- **Why can I call methods of already non-existent objects?** Your temporary object lives at the stack and thus the memory will be freed only at the end of the `main` function, so you are still able to access this memory and it does not get clobbered by calls to other functions (e.g. printing to the terminal). If you would create the object with `new`, than delete it and than try to use it - the chances would be higher, that the system has already reclaimed this memory and you would get a segmentation error.
- **Why I see 2 times the method of B called?** This one is funny. To call a virtual function of an object, compiler delegates the decision which method exactly should be called to a virtual table (it's address occupies the first 8 byte of such an object (at least for my compiler and 64bit)). A not that well known details about virtual methods is that during the destructor-call all virtual methods are called as if they were not virtual. But what has it to do with your code? You see its side-effect: The non-virtual behavior is ensured in the destructor by overwriting the virtual table of the current object by the virtual table of the current class. So after the destructor of `B` is called, the memory contains a virtual table of the class `B` which you can see, because `B::method` is called twice.

Let's track the value of the virtual table it in your program:

1. call of `A{}`: At first the superclass `B`-constructor is called - the (not yet fully finished) object has the virtual table of class `B` (this address is moved into the first 8 byte occupied by the object), than `A`-constructor is called - now the object has the virtual table of class `A`.
2. call of `~A()`: after its execution, the destructor of `A` automatically calls the destructor of `B`. The first thing the destructor of `B` does is to overwrite the virtual table of the object with the virtual table of the class B.
3. So after the destruction the memory is still there and interpreted as an object would have the the virtual table of class `B`.
4. `itr->method();` finds the virtual table of class `B` at the address `itr` points to and calls `B::method()`.